# Selection Sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What changes would we have to make to the selection sort algorithm if we repeatedly chose the largest item in our subarrays, rather than the smallest?

Comment: You have left that homework too late. Do not drink so many cocktails!

Comment: It's gonna be a Tequila Sunrise tomorrow.

Comment: Just change the documentation to say that it's a descending sort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the array backwards. Also, the largest element should be found in (0,j) range.
Here's a modified code from Wikipedia article:

```
/* a[0] to a[n-1] is the array to sort */
int i,j;

/* iterate backwards the position through the entire array */
/*   (could do j > 0 because single element is also min element) */
for (j = n-1; j > 0; j--) {
    /* find the max element in the unsorted a[0 .. j] */

    /* assume the max is the first element */
    int iMax = 0;
    /* test against elements before j to find the largest */
    for ( i = 0; i <= j; i++) {
        /* if this element is greater, then it is the new minimum */
        if (a[i] > a[iMax]) {
            /* found new max; remember its index */
            iMax = i;
        }
    }

    if(iMax != j) {
        swap(a[j], a[iMax]);
    }
}
```